# Map is not a function for trip advisor 3rd party api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tripadvisor

I am using the Trip Advisor API and need to  map over the array of hotels that it is sending me using my API call I have tried this a few different ways but am still getting this error.   I have provided my code and all 3 components in react for reference but everything I have found to fix this error is not doing the trip. [hotelMapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhxX1.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voeSz.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y3Xi.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJYNU.png)
You will notice there is commented out code as I did try this two different ways.

I tried mapping over the array in the same component and I tried to seperate the information being returned by the 3rd party API  and I am still getting the same error. I am expecting the information to come through the console in single hotel formating mening singlehotel  is holding one hotel each.